# undefined reference to `__mingw_vsscanf'

Tags: c++, raylib

I am currently listening to some videos from Udemy.  This one is specifically has to do with using raylib to make a basic game.  So before getting to that the course goes over making a popup window and here is the code that I used below.

```
#include "raylib.h"

int main() {
    InitWindow(300, 500, "test window");
}
```

I downloaded the vscode template that the course was using for this. So from this point I put the template in the following:

1. Create folder GameDev
2. put vscode template in GameDev folder
3. Copy and paste the template so  any changes I would make would not alter the original template.  And that was incase I messed up somehow then I could start over haha. Inside of the template folder this is how it is set up.

[template-folder-contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXakU.png)

So with the code that I posted above initially I had the red squiggly line under #include "raylib.h".  Which took me a while before I finally figured out how to update the include path in configuration settings.  Then the red squiggly line went away.  At that point I clicked on the tab Run, then Start Debugging. In the Terminal it shows this and won't go any farther.  Won't create the popup window.

[terminal-status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtSYI.png)//

Several lines are showing an undefined reference. And that is where I'm not sure what is meant by an undefined reference.  I've clicked on the problems tab and it's not showing any errors.  It looks to me like maybe there is a library or header that isn't linked which is leading to what is seen in the terminal status picture above. That's my best guestimate and won't be surprised if I'm completely wrong about this.  Anything I can learn from here is awesome! And if it helps whoever is willing to look at this here is the launch.json code

```
 "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
        {
          "name": "Debug",
          "type": "cppdbg",
          "request": "launch",
          "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
          "args": [],
          "stopAtEntry": false,
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
          "environment": [],
          "externalConsole": false,
          "MIMode": "gdb",
          "setupCommands": [
            {
              "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
              "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
              "ignoreFailures": false
            }
          ],
          "windows": {
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:/raylib/w64devkit/bin/gdb.exe",
          },
          "osx": {
            "MIMode": "lldb"
          },
          "linux": {
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
          },
          "preLaunchTask": "build debug"
        },
        {
          "name": "Run",
          "type": "cppdbg",
          "request": "launch",
          "args": [],
          "stopAtEntry": false,
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
          "environment": [],
          "externalConsole": false,
          "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
          "MIMode": "gdb",
          "windows": {
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:/raylib/w64devkit/bin/gdb.exe"
          },
          "osx": {
            "MIMode": "lldb"
          },
          "linux": {
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
          },
          "preLaunchTask": "build release",
        }
      ]
    }
```

Last but not least here is the c_cpp_properties.json code

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:/raylib/raylib/src/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/raylib/w64devkit/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/include/c++/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE",
                "GRAPHICS_API_OPENGL_33",
                "PLATFORM_DESKTOP"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/raylib/w64devkit/bin/gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c99",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        },
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/opt/homebrew/include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE",
                "GRAPHICS_API_OPENGL_33",
                "PLATFORM_DESKTOP"
            ],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        },
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/include",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE",
                "GRAPHICS_API_OPENGL_33",
                "PLATFORM_DESKTOP"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

okay and here's the task.json code

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build debug",
            "type": "process",
            "command": "make",
            "args": [
                "PLATFORM=PLATFORM_DESKTOP",
                "BUILD_MODE=DEBUG"
            ],
            "windows": {
                "command": "C:/raylib/w64devkit/bin/mingw32-make.exe",
                "args": [
                    "RAYLIB_PATH=C:/raylib/raylib",
                    "PROJECT_NAME=${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                    "OBJS=*.cpp",
                    "BUILD_MODE=DEBUG"
                ]
            },
            "osx": {
                "args": [
                    "PROJECT_NAME=${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                    "OBJS=*.cpp",
                    "BUILD_MODE=DEBUG"
                ]
            },
            "linux": {
                "args": [
                    "PROJECT_NAME=${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                    "DESTDIR=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew",
                    "RAYLIB_LIBTYPE=SHARED",
                    "EXAMPLE_RUNTIME_PATH=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib",
                    "OBJS=*.cpp",
                    "BUILD_MODE=DEBUG"
                ]
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "build release",
            "type": "process",
            "command": "make",
            "args": [
                "PLATFORM=PLATFORM_DESKTOP"
            ],
            "windows": {
                "command": "C:/raylib/w64devkit/bin/mingw32-make.exe",
                "args": [
                    "RAYLIB_PATH=C:/raylib/raylib",
                    "PROJECT_NAME=${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                    "OBJS=*.cpp"
                ]
            },
            "osx": {
                "args": [
                    "PROJECT_NAME=${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                    "OBJS=*.cpp"
                ]
            },
            "linux": {
                "args": [
                    "PROJECT_NAME=${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                    "DESTDIR=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew",
                    "RAYLIB_LIBTYPE=SHARED",
                    "EXAMPLE_RUNTIME_PATH=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib",
                    "OBJS=*.cpp"
                ]
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": false
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\raylib\\w64devkit\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

here's the makefile:

```
#**************************************************************************************************

.PHONY: all clean

# Define required raylib variables
PROJECT_NAME       ?= game
RAYLIB_VERSION     ?= 3.0.0
RAYLIB_API_VERSION ?= 300
RAYLIB_PATH        ?= ..\..

# Define compiler path on Windows
COMPILER_PATH      ?= C:/raylib/mingw/bin

# Define default options
# One of PLATFORM_DESKTOP, PLATFORM_RPI, PLATFORM_ANDROID, PLATFORM_WEB
PLATFORM           ?= PLATFORM_DESKTOP

# Locations of your newly installed library and associated headers. See ../src/Makefile
# On Linux, if you have installed raylib but cannot compile the examples, check that
# the *_INSTALL_PATH values here are the same as those in src/Makefile or point to known locations.
# To enable system-wide compile-time and runtime linking to libraylib.so, run ../src/$ sudo make install RAYLIB_LIBTYPE_SHARED.
# To enable compile-time linking to a special version of libraylib.so, change these variables here.
# To enable runtime linking to a special version of libraylib.so, see EXAMPLE_RUNTIME_PATH below.
# If there is a libraylib in both EXAMPLE_RUNTIME_PATH and RAYLIB_INSTALL_PATH, at runtime,
# the library at EXAMPLE_RUNTIME_PATH, if present, will take precedence over the one at RAYLIB_INSTALL_PATH.
# RAYLIB_INSTALL_PATH should be the desired full path to libraylib. No relative paths.
DESTDIR ?= /usr/local
RAYLIB_INSTALL_PATH ?= $(DESTDIR)/lib
# RAYLIB_H_INSTALL_PATH locates the installed raylib header and associated source files.
RAYLIB_H_INSTALL_PATH ?= $(DESTDIR)/include

# Library type used for raylib: STATIC (.a) or SHARED (.so/.dll)
RAYLIB_LIBTYPE        ?= STATIC

# Build mode for project: DEBUG or RELEASE
BUILD_MODE            ?= RELEASE

# Use external GLFW library instead of rglfw module
# TODO: Review usage on Linux. Target version of choice. Switch on -lglfw or -lglfw3
USE_EXTERNAL_GLFW     ?= FALSE

# Use Wayland display server protocol on Linux desktop
# by default it uses X11 windowing system
USE_WAYLAND_DISPLAY   ?= FALSE

# Determine PLATFORM_OS in case PLATFORM_DESKTOP selected
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_DESKTOP)
    # No uname.exe on MinGW!, but OS=Windows_NT on Windows!
    # ifeq ($(UNAME),Msys) -> Windows
    ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
        PLATFORM_OS=WINDOWS
        export PATH := $(COMPILER_PATH):$(PATH)
    else
        UNAMEOS=$(shell uname)
        ifeq ($(UNAMEOS),Linux)
            PLATFORM_OS=LINUX
        endif
        ifeq ($(UNAMEOS),FreeBSD)
            PLATFORM_OS=BSD
        endif
        ifeq ($(UNAMEOS),OpenBSD)
            PLATFORM_OS=BSD
        endif
        ifeq ($(UNAMEOS),NetBSD)
            PLATFORM_OS=BSD
        endif
        ifeq ($(UNAMEOS),DragonFly)
            PLATFORM_OS=BSD
        endif
        ifeq ($(UNAMEOS),Darwin)
            PLATFORM_OS=OSX
        endif
    endif
endif
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_RPI)
    UNAMEOS=$(shell uname)
    ifeq ($(UNAMEOS),Linux)
        PLATFORM_OS=LINUX
    endif
endif

# RAYLIB_PATH adjustment for different platforms.
# If using GNU make, we can get the full path to the top of the tree. Windows? BSD?
# Required for ldconfig or other tools that do not perform path expansion.
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_DESKTOP)
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),LINUX)
        RAYLIB_PREFIX ?= ..
        RAYLIB_PATH    = $(realpath $(RAYLIB_PREFIX))
    endif
endif
# Default path for raylib on Raspberry Pi, if installed in different path, update it!
# This is not currently used by src/Makefile. Not sure of its origin or usage. Refer to wiki.
# TODO: update install: target in src/Makefile for RPI, consider relation to LINUX.
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_RPI)
    RAYLIB_PATH       ?= /home/pi/raylib
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_WEB)
    # Emscripten required variables
    EMSDK_PATH          ?= C:/emsdk
    EMSCRIPTEN_VERSION  ?= 1.38.31
    CLANG_VERSION       = e$(EMSCRIPTEN_VERSION)_64bit
    PYTHON_VERSION      = 2.7.13.1_64bit\python-2.7.13.amd64
    NODE_VERSION        = 8.9.1_64bit
    export PATH         = $(EMSDK_PATH);$(EMSDK_PATH)\clang\$(CLANG_VERSION);$(EMSDK_PATH)\node\$(NODE_VERSION)\bin;$(EMSDK_PATH)\python\$(PYTHON_VERSION);$(EMSDK_PATH)\emscripten\$(EMSCRIPTEN_VERSION);C:\raylib\MinGW\bin:$$(PATH)
    EMSCRIPTEN          = $(EMSDK_PATH)\emscripten\$(EMSCRIPTEN_VERSION)
endif

# Define raylib release directory for compiled library.
# RAYLIB_RELEASE_PATH points to provided binaries or your freshly built version
RAYLIB_RELEASE_PATH     ?= $(RAYLIB_PATH)/src

# EXAMPLE_RUNTIME_PATH embeds a custom runtime location of libraylib.so or other desired libraries
# into each example binary compiled with RAYLIB_LIBTYPE=SHARED. It defaults to RAYLIB_RELEASE_PATH
# so that these examples link at runtime with your version of libraylib.so in ../release/libs/linux
# without formal installation from ../src/Makefile. It aids portability and is useful if you have
# multiple versions of raylib, have raylib installed to a non-standard location, or want to
# bundle libraylib.so with your game. Change it to your liking.
# NOTE: If, at runtime, there is a libraylib.so at both EXAMPLE_RUNTIME_PATH and RAYLIB_INSTALL_PATH,
# The library at EXAMPLE_RUNTIME_PATH, if present, will take precedence over RAYLIB_INSTALL_PATH,
# Implemented for LINUX below with CFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath,$(EXAMPLE_RUNTIME_PATH)
# To see the result, run readelf -d core/core_basic_window; looking at the RPATH or RUNPATH attribute.
# To see which libraries a built example is linking to, ldd core/core_basic_window;
# Look for libraylib.so.1 => $(RAYLIB_INSTALL_PATH)/libraylib.so.1 or similar listing.
EXAMPLE_RUNTIME_PATH   ?= $(RAYLIB_RELEASE_PATH)

# Define default C compiler: gcc
# NOTE: define g++ compiler if using C++
CC = g++

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_DESKTOP)
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),OSX)
        # OSX default compiler
        CC = clang++
    endif
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),BSD)
        # FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD, DragonFly default compiler
        CC = clang
    endif
endif
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_RPI)
    ifeq ($(USE_RPI_CROSS_COMPILER),TRUE)
        # Define RPI cross-compiler
        #CC = armv6j-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi-gcc
        CC = $(RPI_TOOLCHAIN)/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
    endif
endif
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_WEB)
    # HTML5 emscripten compiler
    # WARNING: To compile to HTML5, code must be redesigned 
    # to use emscripten.h and emscripten_set_main_loop()
    CC = emcc
endif

# Define default make program: Mingw32-make
MAKE = mingw32-make

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_DESKTOP)
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),LINUX)
        MAKE = make
    endif
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),OSX)
        MAKE = make
    endif
endif

# Define compiler flags:
#  -O0                  defines optimization level (no optimization, better for debugging)
#  -O1                  defines optimization level
#  -g                   include debug information on compilation
#  -s                   strip unnecessary data from build -> do not use in debug builds
#  -Wall                turns on most, but not all, compiler warnings
#  -std=c99             defines C language mode (standard C from 1999 revision)
#  -std=gnu99           defines C language mode (GNU C from 1999 revision)
#  -Wno-missing-braces  ignore invalid warning (GCC bug 53119)
#  -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE    use with -std=c99 on Linux and PLATFORM_WEB, required for timespec
CFLAGS += -Wall -std=c++14 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -Wno-missing-braces

ifeq ($(BUILD_MODE),DEBUG)
    CFLAGS += -g -O0
else
    CFLAGS += -s -O1
endif

# Additional flags for compiler (if desired)
#CFLAGS += -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_DESKTOP)
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),WINDOWS)
        # resource file contains windows executable icon and properties
        # -Wl,--subsystem,windows hides the console window
        CFLAGS += $(RAYLIB_PATH)/src/raylib.rc.data
    endif
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),LINUX)
        ifeq ($(RAYLIB_LIBTYPE),STATIC)
            CFLAGS += -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE
        endif
        ifeq ($(RAYLIB_LIBTYPE),SHARED)
            # Explicitly enable runtime link to libraylib.so
            CFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath,$(EXAMPLE_RUNTIME_PATH)
        endif
    endif
endif
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_RPI)
    CFLAGS += -std=gnu99
endif
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_WEB)
    # -Os                        # size optimization
    # -O2                        # optimization level 2, if used, also set --memory-init-file 0
    # -s USE_GLFW=3              # Use glfw3 library (context/input management)
    # -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1   # to allow memory resizing -> WARNING: Audio buffers could FAIL!
    # -s TOTAL_MEMORY=16777216   # to specify heap memory size (default = 16MB)
    # -s USE_PTHREADS=1          # multithreading support
    # -s WASM=0                  # disable Web Assembly, emitted by default
    # -s EMTERPRETIFY=1          # enable emscripten code interpreter (very slow)
    # -s EMTERPRETIFY_ASYNC=1    # support synchronous loops by emterpreter
    # -s FORCE_FILESYSTEM=1      # force filesystem to load/save files data
    # -s ASSERTIONS=1            # enable runtime checks for common memory allocation errors (-O1 and above turn it off)
    # --profiling                # include information for code profiling
    # --memory-init-file 0       # to avoid an external memory initialization code file (.mem)
    # --preload-file resources   # specify a resources folder for data compilation
    CFLAGS += -Os -s USE_GLFW=3 -s TOTAL_MEMORY=16777216 --preload-file resources
    ifeq ($(BUILD_MODE), DEBUG)
        CFLAGS += -s ASSERTIONS=1 --profiling
    endif

    # Define a custom shell .html and output extension
    CFLAGS += --shell-file $(RAYLIB_PATH)/src/shell.html
    EXT = .html
endif

# Define include paths for required headers
# NOTE: Several external required libraries (stb and others)
INCLUDE_PATHS = -I. -I$(RAYLIB_PATH)/src -I$(RAYLIB_PATH)/src/external
ifneq ($(wildcard /opt/homebrew/include/.*),)
    INCLUDE_PATHS += -I/opt/homebrew/include
endif

# Define additional directories containing required header files
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_RPI)
    # RPI required libraries
    INCLUDE_PATHS += -I/opt/vc/include
    INCLUDE_PATHS += -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vmcs_host/linux
    INCLUDE_PATHS += -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads
endif
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_DESKTOP)
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),BSD)
        # Consider -L$(RAYLIB_H_INSTALL_PATH)
        INCLUDE_PATHS += -I/usr/local/include
    endif
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),LINUX)
        # Reset everything.
        # Precedence: immediately local, installed version, raysan5 provided libs -I$(RAYLIB_H_INSTALL_PATH) -I$(RAYLIB_PATH)/release/include
        INCLUDE_PATHS = -I$(RAYLIB_H_INSTALL_PATH) -isystem. -isystem$(RAYLIB_PATH)/src -isystem$(RAYLIB_PATH)/release/include -isystem$(RAYLIB_PATH)/src/external
    endif
endif

# Define library paths containing required libs.
LDFLAGS = -L.

ifneq ($(wildcard $(RAYLIB_RELEASE_PATH)/.*),)
    LDFLAGS += -L$(RAYLIB_RELEASE_PATH)
endif
ifneq ($(wildcard $(RAYLIB_PATH)/src/.*),)
    LDFLAGS += -L$(RAYLIB_PATH)/src
endif
ifneq ($(wildcard /opt/homebrew/lib/.*),)
    LDFLAGS += -L/opt/homebrew/lib
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_DESKTOP)
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),BSD)
        # Consider -L$(RAYLIB_INSTALL_PATH)
        LDFLAGS += -L. -Lsrc -L/usr/local/lib
    endif
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),LINUX)
        # Reset everything.
        # Precedence: immediately local, installed version, raysan5 provided libs
        LDFLAGS = -L. -L$(RAYLIB_INSTALL_PATH) -L$(RAYLIB_RELEASE_PATH)
    endif
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_RPI)
    LDFLAGS += -L/opt/vc/lib
endif

# Define any libraries required on linking
# if you want to link libraries (libname.so or libname.a), use the -lname
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_DESKTOP)
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),WINDOWS)
        # Libraries for Windows desktop compilation
        # NOTE: WinMM library required to set high-res timer resolution
        LDLIBS = -lraylib -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm
        # Required for physac examples
        #LDLIBS += -static -lpthread
    endif
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),LINUX)
        # Libraries for Debian GNU/Linux desktop compiling
        # NOTE: Required packages: libegl1-mesa-dev
        LDLIBS = -lraylib -lGL -lm -lpthread -ldl -lrt
        
        # On X11 requires also below libraries
        LDLIBS += -lX11
        # NOTE: It seems additional libraries are not required any more, latest GLFW just dlopen them
        #LDLIBS += -lXrandr -lXinerama -lXi -lXxf86vm -lXcursor
        
        # On Wayland windowing system, additional libraries requires
        ifeq ($(USE_WAYLAND_DISPLAY),TRUE)
            LDLIBS += -lwayland-client -lwayland-cursor -lwayland-egl -lxkbcommon
        endif
        # Explicit link to libc
        ifeq ($(RAYLIB_LIBTYPE),SHARED)
            LDLIBS += -lc
        endif
    endif
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),OSX)
        # Libraries for OSX 10.9 desktop compiling
        # NOTE: Required packages: libopenal-dev libegl1-mesa-dev
        LDLIBS = -lraylib -framework OpenGL -framework OpenAL -framework Cocoa -framework IOKit
    endif
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),BSD)
        # Libraries for FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD, DragonFly desktop compiling
        # NOTE: Required packages: mesa-libs
        LDLIBS = -lraylib -lGL -lpthread -lm

        # On XWindow requires also below libraries
        LDLIBS += -lX11 -lXrandr -lXinerama -lXi -lXxf86vm -lXcursor
    endif
    ifeq ($(USE_EXTERNAL_GLFW),TRUE)
        # NOTE: It could require additional packages installed: libglfw3-dev
        LDLIBS += -lglfw
    endif
endif
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_RPI)
    # Libraries for Raspberry Pi compiling
    # NOTE: Required packages: libasound2-dev (ALSA)
    LDLIBS = -lraylib -lbrcmGLESv2 -lbrcmEGL -lpthread -lrt -lm -lbcm_host -ldl
endif
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_WEB)
    # Libraries for web (HTML5) compiling
    LDLIBS = $(RAYLIB_RELEASE_PATH)/libraylib.bc
endif

# Define a recursive wildcard function
rwildcard=$(foreach d,$(wildcard $1*),$(call rwildcard,$d/,$2) $(filter $(subst *,%,$2),$d))

# Define all source files required
SRC_DIR = src
OBJ_DIR = obj

# Define all object files from source files
SRC = $(call rwildcard, *.c, *.h)
#OBJS = $(SRC:$(SRC_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
OBJS ?= main.c

# For Android platform we call a custom Makefile.Android
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_ANDROID)
    MAKEFILE_PARAMS = -f Makefile.Android 
    export PROJECT_NAME
    export SRC_DIR
else
    MAKEFILE_PARAMS = $(PROJECT_NAME)
endif

# Default target entry
# NOTE: We call this Makefile target or Makefile.Android target
all:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKEFILE_PARAMS)

# Project target defined by PROJECT_NAME
$(PROJECT_NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $(PROJECT_NAME)$(EXT) $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) -D$(PLATFORM)

# Compile source files
# NOTE: This pattern will compile every module defined on $(OBJS)
#%.o: %.c
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) -D$(PLATFORM)

# Clean everything
clean:
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_DESKTOP)
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),WINDOWS)
        del *.o *.exe /s
    endif
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),LINUX)
    find -type f -executable | xargs file -i | grep -E 'x-object|x-archive|x-sharedlib|x-executable' | rev | cut -d ':' -f 2- | rev | xargs rm -fv
    endif
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),OSX)
        find . -type f -perm +ugo+x -delete
        rm -f *.o
    endif
endif
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_RPI)
    find . -type f -executable -delete
    rm -fv *.o
endif
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_WEB)
    del *.o *.html *.js
endif
    @echo Cleaning done
```

here is the output after "clean"

```
> Executing task in folder project14: C:/raylib/w64devkit/bin/mingw32-make.exe RAYLIB_PATH=C:/raylib/raylib PROJECT_NAME=axe_game OBJS=*.cpp BUILD_MODE=DEBUG <

mingw32-make axe_game
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/GameDev/project14'
g++ -o axe_game *.cpp -Wall -std=c++14 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -Wno-missing-braces -g -O0 C:/raylib/raylib/src/raylib.rc.data -I. -IC:/raylib/raylib/src -IC:/raylib/raylib/src/external -L. -LC:/raylib/raylib/src -LC:/raylib/raylib/src -lraylib -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -DPLATFORM_DESKTOP
C:/raylib/raylib/src/libraylib.a(rcore.o):rcore.c:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `__mingw_vsscanf'       
C:/raylib/raylib/src/libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `__mingw_vsscanf'       
C:/raylib/raylib/src/libraylib.a(rtextures.o):rtextures.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `__mingw_strtod'
C:/raylib/raylib/src/libraylib.a(rtext.o):rtext.c:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `__mingw_vsscanf'      
C:/raylib/raylib/src/libraylib.a(utils.o):utils.c:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `_imp____acrt_iob_func'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:392: recipe for target 'axe_game' failed        
mingw32-make[1]: *** [axe_game] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/GameDev/project14'
make: *** [Makefile:388: all] Error 2
The terminal process "C:\raylib\w64devkit\bin\mingw32-make.exe 'RAYLIB_PATH=C:/raylib/raylib', 'PROJECT_NAME=axe_game', 'OBJS=*.cpp', 'BUILD_MODE=DEBUG'" terminated with exit code: 2.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Comment: The `tasks.json` file is more interesting than the `launch.json` file. Please [edit] your question to show the `tasks.json` file instead.

Comment: okay I added the tasks.json code @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: It might be useful to see the `Makefile` too. As well as a full and complete copy-paste of the build output after a "clean". Seeing the commands that `make` runs, and especially the options and flags and their *order* will be interesting. Because the order in which you link things might be an issue. It might also be an issue if raylib was built with a different version of MinGW. Did you install raylib from a binary package, or build from source?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I finally got a break at work so I got the makefile added.  then copy pasted the output.  And to answer your question I installed raylib from a binary package.  And that was from the raylib website.

Comment: A quick search doesn't turn up much, other than it's a possible mismatch between compiler versions used to build the library, and the version used to build your application. Possibly 32-bit versus 64-bit could also be an issue. How did you install MinGW? What version of GCC are you using?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the version of gcc that I'm using and this is what I got from running gcc --version in command prompt.  gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0.  And as far as how I installed MiniGW I'll include the link to code.visualstudio.com.  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw   That is how I installed it although I did have to go into environment variables and update the path to make sure.  and then as far as the instructions from code.visualstudio.com it appears to have been installed since when I type those commands in command prompt it tells me the version.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude hey I really appreciate your responses to my question.  I spent a lot of time trying to digest you saying there possibly being a mismatch between compiler versions used to build the library, and the version used to build the application.  That is exactly what happened!  Took me until this morning to figure out my dum**** didn't have the compiler in raylib in the system path.  I feel so incredibly dumb for that.  Then it didn't actually work until I updated the compiler path in the makefile......lol now I won't forget that.  Thanks again every little bit I learn will help!!

Comment: It was just a hunch from my side (having experienced similar problems myself earlier). Glad it worked out! :) I think you should write a proper answer, as it might be an issue for others and a proper answer is always nicer. :)

Comment: I mean write an actual answer in the section below, one that can be voted on and accepted (by yourself).

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to write the best answer so others can use this. I'm using raylib learning how to make a basic game. If you are using VS Code and are seeing output messages saying "undefined reference", not seeing any red squiggly line errors, then the first thing you should try to look at is your path settings in the environment variable settings. This is in Windows and I'm using Windows 10. If you don't have this setup in the environment variables then more than likely it won't be picked up by VS Code. Then in VS Code make sure that path is set in makefile and in c/c++ configurations settings